# Place certain article anywhere in joomla template

Tags: joomla

Is it possible in Joomla to place a certain article in a template, additionally to the normal content? I want the article to show up on every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply take it from the databse and print its content. In the template, where you want to show the article, write this:

```
$id=/*Id of the article to show*/;
$db=&JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE id=$id");
$item=$db->loadObject();
echo $item->introtext;
```

**UPDATE: ENABLE PLUGINS**

I can't find where i've used that code and i can't copy-paste it, so i try to write it again by looking at the view.html.php of the com_content:

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content');
$dispatcher =& JDispatcher::getInstance();
$params = &$mainframe->getParams();
$dispatcher->trigger('onPrepareContent', array (&$item, &$params, 0));
//The last line triggers the onPrepareContent event, so if it does not work maybe you need other events, so try with onAfterDisplayTitle, onBeforeDisplayContent or onAfterDisplayContent
```

Comment: Your answer does solve the question but it is a hack to the template code. Other people have solved this issue by making specific modules/plugins that do so using good practices.

Comment: First: my answer solves the problem because it works. Second: it's not an hack it's a query nothing more. Third: every module does exactly the same thing that i wrote, so do you really need to use a module to do a basic thing like this?

Comment: This solution however does not consider module stuff in the content like the simple gallery tags ({gallery}..{/gallery})...

Comment: This wasn't written in the question, anyway you can do it by activating the content plugins. I don't write the code because if my answer was an hack this will be a super hack. Anyway i don't want to criticize you, but i don't like people that downvotes because the answer is not the solution that they would use. If it works it's good, if not it should be downvoted.

Comment: It wasn't me who down voted you, I don't mind using the hack anyway if my boss is happy ;)

Comment: ... which implies I don't mind using the super hack. Could you provide me the code? The plug-in mentioned in the other solution doesn't look like it activates the content plug-ins neither.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this? http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/content-embed/7528

It allows you to place any article as a module on your Joomla site. And with modules you can have them displayed site wide.

Comment: This looks quite useful. I just don't quite get how it works.. Where do I give the article ID? (I'm very new to Joomla)

Comment: You install the module and then activate it. In the module settings you would fill in the article id.